# xctest won't load in application, code signing seems to be wrong

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, code-signing, xctest

I've been struggling to implement unit tests in an existing project for almost 2 days now. I think it's time I ask for some help...

Context:

- We have an existing application
- While there is a test target in that project, it has never been used so far
- The application can only run on the device (some of the libs we use are closed source and arm only.)
- We're using CocoaPods

So I figured I'd just hit cmd-U and run the unit tests. Piece of cake!

Wrong!

When I try to run the tests, I'm gratified with this message:

```
2014-12-01 13:21:09.506 <Project>[775:60b] Error loading /private/var/mobile/Applications/2CB132E3-A3BB-411B-9222-DBD20CE6D566/tmp/<Project>Tests.xctest/<Project>Tests:  dlopen(/private/var/mobile/Applications/2CB132E3-A3BB-411B-9222-DBD20CE6D566/tmp/<Project>Tests.xctest/<Project>Tests, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Applications/2CB132E3-A3BB-411B-9222-DBD20CE6D566/tmp/<Project>Tests.xctest/<Project>Tests: code signature invalid for '/private/var/mobile/Applications/2CB132E3-A3BB-411B-9222-DBD20CE6D566/tmp/<Project>Tests.xctest/<Project>Tests'
DevToolsBundleInjection: Error loading bundle '/private/var/mobile/Applications/2CB132E3-A3BB-411B-9222-DBD20CE6D566/tmp/<Project>Tests.xctest'
```

(btw, I can't disclose the project name, so whatever is `<Project>` up here is actually the project name.)

It seems to complain about code signing which would be invalid.

Despite my attempts to DoS google with search terms, loads of fiddling with code signing identities and stuff, I couldn't find a solution to this problem. I even created another small project from scratch, which ran the tests like a charm.

I'm out of fresh ideas. Do you have some for me?

Comment: Indeed, I'm having the same issue, and all signatures and provisioning profiles fail. Have you had any success?